# Dart 2.7.1 webdev 2.5.4 build throws Unhandled exception: Instance of 'MissingPortFile'

Tags: dart, angular-dart

after upgrading Dart to 2.7.1 I get an `Unhandled exception: Instance of 'MissingPortFile'` when building the app with webdev 2.5.4. I have two AngularDart projects (Owner, Admin) sharing some code (Common). When I run webdev in Admin, I get the exception on the first run, on the second it starts. When I run webdev in Owner, I get the exception every time and then it won't start. The webdev command is the same in both projects (except the port number).

Admin: `pub global activate webdev 2.5.4 && pub global run webdev serve --auto=refresh --hostname 127.0.0.1 "web:53311"`

Owner: `pub global activate webdev 2.5.4 && pub global run webdev serve --auto=refresh --hostname 127.0.0.1 "web:53322"`

When I switch to devel Dart (2.8.0-dev.5.0) it works fine in both projects every time.

Is it some known issue of Dart 2.7.x? I didn't find it too much, except https://gitter.im/dart-lang/angular. They mention it should work when invoking webdev from Webstorm IDE, it didn't help me.

Edit: (more observations). After a successful build with Dart 2.8.0-dev5.0 I switched back to 2.7.1 and webdev started fine. So I removed `.dart_tool` folder and restarted webdev (still on Dart 2.7.1) and I got the exception again. So the problem is maybe in some files generated in `.dart_tool`.

Edit2: it's Dart independent. After several runs, I encountered the same problem with Dart 2.8.0-dev.5.0 and vice versa I succeeded with Dart 2.7.1 after several runs. But it's very unstable and I cannot determine what's the problem. From the exception desc `MissingProtFile` I would suspect that webdev creates some port file during build and some other process removes this file meanwhile. Maybe the file is created in some tmp directory. Can someone confirm my suspicion?

Comment: What does your pubspec.yaml look like

Comment: Hello @BrianGorman 
https://github.com/anycode/dart-asv-client-common/blob/master/pubspec.yaml
https://github.com/anycode/dart-asv-client-owner/blob/master/pubspec.yaml
https://github.com/anycode/dart-asv-client-admin/blob/master/pubspec.yaml
Just for information, this problem started after upgrading Dart to 2.7.1. I'll try to downgrade to verify.

Comment: Workaround mentioned in gitter / dart-angular works for me: pub run build_runner serve web:53322

Comment: @vasquez , thanks for hint, I'll try it